# convert DD/MMM/YYYY into a binary/epoch date javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i am trying to convert dd/mmm/yyyy into a binary/epoch date.

example:

```
06/mar/2015
```

into

```
1425600000000
```

i build up my date

```
var Buildup = day + slash + month + slash + year;
```

but now i dont have a clue how to do it i have tried something like this:

```
    var formattedDays = Buildup.split(" ")[0].split("-");
    var epoch = new Date(formattedDays[0], formattedDays[1] - 1, formattedDays[2]).getSeconds;
var epochStart = new Date(formattedDays[0], formattedDays[1] - 1,formattedDays[2],formattedTime[0],formattedTime[1],formattedTime[2],0).getTime()/1000;
```

but no look?

Comment: For date manipulation, the best library is http://momentjs.com/ then do something like `moment("06/mar/2015", "DD/MMM/YYYY").unix()`

Comment: It would be best if you stuck to standard formats, using a number instead of text for the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this :

```
var d = new Date('06/03/2015');
var n = d.getTime();
```

[Date Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

[GetTime Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp)

Comment: how can i apply that with my variable?